# Calling .ex or .exs via ajax

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm wanting to do something like this in Phoenix

```
function checkFile() {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/check.ex',
                    data: {'filename':'file.png'},
                    error : function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){ checkFile(); }, 3000);
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                            // display the image
                    }
            });
    }
```

to check if a file gets created, then display the image through js. But of course `/` routes to main page, and I'm not quite sure the best way to set up the routing or where to put standalone .ex or .exs files. I was wondering if there was a standard way of solving that. Probably an article or something on phoenixframework.org I'm missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the .ex file directly, what you want to do is create an API resource.

It might look something like the following.

Add to `router.ex`:

```
resources "/images/:filename", ImageController, only: [:show]
```

Create a new `image_controller.ex`:

```
defmodule YourApp.ImageController do
  use YourApp.Web, :controller

  def show(conn, %{"filename" => filename}) do
    image_path   = Path.join("path/to/image", filename)
    image_exists = File.regular?(image_path)

    if image_exists do
      render(conn, "show.json", image: filename)
    else
      conn
      |> put_status(:not_found)
      |> render("404.json", image: filename)
    end
  end
end
```

Create an `image_view.ex`:

```
defmodule YourApp.ImageView do
  use YourApp.Web, :view

  def render("show.json", %{image: filename}) do
    %{data: %{image: filename}}
  end

  def render("404.json", %{image: filename}) do
    %{status: 404, message: "#{filename} doesn't exist."}
  end
end
```

Now you should be able to change your javascript:

```js
function checkFile() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/images/file.png',
    error : function(){
      setTimeout(function(){ checkFile(); }, 3000);
    },
    success : function(data) {
      // display the image
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah great! Just what I was looking for. That makes a lot of sense... I can see how making .ex's unable to be executed directly is more secure, and it's cleaner and more intelligent to just GET the file itself. Much better than the 'classic' way of executing .php's left and right, methinks. Many thanks

Comment: As an addition to the answer, I discovered I can just have the file in `web\static\assets\images`, which gets served automatically via the url `/images/`, which seems perhaps to suffice for what I want. Another thing about this answer as is is that I have to go to `/images/file.png/1`, since `resources` seems to automatically include the /:id path. Also, I don't really need JSON but the image itself, though that could be useful in the future.